# Getting pycharm to work with subversion 1.8.x

Tags: svn, pycharm

The latest version of pycharm 3.0.2 does not work with subversion-1.8, so as a workaround I then use old version of the subversion tree which I scp-ed over from my old machine.

The problem is now I can only update my subversion tree from PyCharm and trying to do svn updated from cli results in errors such as:

```
is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.5 (r1542147)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

Anyone know of a better workaround or how to get subversion-1.8.x working correctly with PyCharm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN 1.8 should work in PyCharm 3.1 Early Access Preview: http://eap.jetbrains.com/pycharm/